# Intuit App: Error while getting accessTokenKey for OAuth 2.0

Tags: php, api, oauth, intuit-partner-platform

I am new in Quickbooks and want to use the API by OAuth 2.0 protocol. For that, I did the following steps according to Quickbooks docs.

1. I have created an Intuit Developer account.
2. I have created an application for testing purposes.
3. I got OAuth keys for my test application.
4. I want to do API requests by using PHP SDK provided by Quickbooks and I started to use code according to the instructions of PHP SDK:

   ```
       require "vendor/autoload.php";
       use QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService;    
       $dataService = DataService::Configure(array(
       'auth_mode' => 'oauth2',
       'ClientID' => "Q0lCkcEshsGMHOEula2r5RKc2yhxvMsYEpKN1lw1WZwyfd1Si6",
       'ClientSecret' => "gE0F9hLgwx9OBzRpNxyOvWJH6L2fIhzAwBugPJHq",
       'accessTokenKey' => 'eyJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2IiwiYWxnIjoiZGlyIn0..4z4Assj4x1qt8H4DtQco6A.nmV2jTxaDMVdFWEUO16q5qhbd5aD6U-U-RYnSNywqg-HPC_3_jvwpMJU1a1S5X-PgPUy60WvVy_8p1awY7kIoFzTV4IhdFLrZpYtBUGCjcsvjxWeOSgP6oCayBEmCv7zzabtgB6vxU46jQqKX2IXYUGPPtyYO64hrgELFR4SKUK6boZiVnh8z19gnvsReKMmIINA3-NgC6QJqMRp6HWgzCa9RuDN9tCtrAK2dy5xmJRNSNgdv_gyg1bfdX4l4b30fLPzFk31fsTT9NTJq9PuGtdTsvUuCj7Hme6HPldD9TKYRXWU8TKrQQrQWEpdlbPr6F3rhP6IdmCv9t1XH_WzF_1IseRUoYhiTUjubig-j8gzwajIdYQTzpJQKJ92QiAEyt8k40WWg0v69hEC0w7WRBuUE-IJ50xWypqS_P28IWt1G14rovZ97soGOteSik-41g1icR2zxfNhXGq7zO7oU5B8r-ej5Pb52T0MCMktgd6y32bqwo2pcEzblL2bZs7DZ7LDx5peY4TIfGW21crTE6xjhRr7LdqB8K505pRqIOP20eaRgwtGHLZ3bdBt1_negw2AGjc409BM0nLzzmODxr3yo-YdGwkcOjm5QgbGAsrnpoSo9tSpxPHoN0vMRneRdsKCd6CZG5M1OIOMuj7spkm442tvwiAMCx2Fh-STG6fMnhOq7l_f8NW_3kscxtF2.obQxJKjPfi1KlaQQ_OUoNg',
       'refreshTokenKey' => "L011509163184Q0K7DT40SVXhJXAfyoj6B6EbSr3Ty64yVvF5A",
       'QBORealmID' => "123145857569084",
       'baseUrl' => "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com"
   ));
   ```
5. I am stacked on getting **accessTokenKey** in order to complete configurations and start to do API requests. QuickBooks provides a tool named **OAuth Playground** here for getting **accessTokenKey**. I put **Client ID** and **Client Secret** from Application's Keys as **Consumer Key** and **Consumer Secret** in the **OAuth Playground's** screen and press Connect to QiuckBooks but it gives me this error:

   ```
   We were unable to process your request.

   This error can occur when too much time has passed in the request. We have been notified of the problem and will investigate further.

   Please contact us for further assistance.
   Error Id: cxgdknrkjzppmjifkv2ipsgp-29491421
   ```

Could anyone help me with this error?